# Making an argument optional in terraform resource block

Tags: terraform

Can we make argument usage present in a resource block optional
for eg like in below resource block table_name , mapping_rule_name and data_format are optional parameter and I want to have a standard format for terraform where I can make these values optional for e.g like if **var.table_name** variable has value it should provide it to table_name otherwise table_name should be ignored i.e. eventhubconnection be formed without table_name,mapping_rule_name and data_format as these are optional value

```
resource "azurerm_kusto_eventhub_data_connection" "eventhub_connection" {
  name                = "my-kusto-eventhub-data-connection"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  cluster_name        = azurerm_kusto_cluster.cluster.name
  database_name       = azurerm_kusto_database.database.name

  eventhub_id    = azurerm_eventhub.eventhub.id
  consumer_group = azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group.consumer_group.name

  table_name        = var.table_name       #(Optional)
  mapping_rule_name = var.mapping_rule_name #(Optional)
  data_format       = var.data_format          #(Optional)
}
```

Is there any way to do that in terraform?

Comment: I can only think of a ternary operator usage in this case: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/conditionals#syntax.

Comment: Also if those variables are assigned a value of `null` then the argument will be ignored, so you can achieve this with only input values if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Conditionally Omitted Arguments](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements#conditionally-omitted-arguments), which allow for variables with the value `null` to be interpreted as "unset" by Terraform. I like to use the following pattern to make more "toggle-able" attributes leveraging this feature:

#### Defining variables

```
# variables.tf
variable "table_name" {
  type    = string
  # ...
  default = null
}
variable "mapping_rule_name" {
  type    = string
  # ...
  default = null
}
```

#### Initializing variables

```
# myterraform.tfvars
table_name = "my-table-name"
```

#### Using Conditionally Omitted Arguments

```
# eventhub.tf
resource "azurerm_kusto_eventhub_data_connection" "eventhub_connection" {
  # ...
  table_name        = var.table_name        # instantiated to value in .tfvars
  mapping_rule_name = var.mapping_rule_name # is "unset" by default null value
}
```

---

If you'd like to do the same, but with nested blocks of attributes instead of just attributes, you can check out [Dynamic Nested Blocks](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) and apply conditional logic to determine whether said blocks will be generated.